# Get text wrapped into <b> and separated by <br> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I receive the output from services in html string format as follow :

```
"<html>↵<h1>↵Example : ↵<br>Explanation↵</h1>↵<hr>↵<b>key1 :  ABCD <br>key2 : 2016-10-18-18-38-29<br>Output: /acddfd/example</b>↵</html>↵"
```

Then I parse the html to get tag `<b>` as follows:

```
var input="<html>↵<head>↵<h1>↵Example : ↵<br>Explanation↵</h1>↵<hr>↵<b>key1 :  ABCD <br>key2 : 2016-10-18-18-38-29<br>Output: /acddfd/example</b>↵</html>↵";
var parsed= $.parseHTML(input);
```

Then I find parsed as an array of html tags:

```
<b>key1 :  ABCD <br>Date : 2016-10-18-18-38-29<br>Output: /acddfd/example</b>
```

Now I need to get the value of **Date** for further operation.
Can anyone help me to get the value of **Date** (e.g.`2016-10-18-18-38-29`) using js/jquery?

Comment: I thinks jQuery won't be of much help because it's made to navigate through  the dom. Since your date isn't wrapped in HTML tags that can be identified via css classes or Ids you might as well just use a regex on the plain string `input`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex

```
var Date= str.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property to get sibling text after element. It return `Date : 2016-10-18-18-38-29` and you need to remove additional part from string.

Use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get string after `:` character.

```
$(parsed).find("br:first")[0].nextSibling.textContent.split(":")[1].trim();
```

```js
var date = $("b > br:first")[0].nextSibling.textContent.split(":")[1].trim();
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>key1 :  ABCD <br>Date : 2016-10-18-18-38-29<br>Output: /acddfd/example</b>
```

Comment: Hello, i am getting an error on Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined(…).

Comment: @kulfi Did you used `$(parsed).find("br:first")[0].nextSibling`?

Comment: @kulfi Javascript variable is casesenstive. `$(Parsed)` is different with `$(parsed)`

Comment: I used as follow  $(parsed).find("br:first")[0].nextSibling.textContent.split(":")[1].trim();

Comment: @kulfi The code is right and work in snippet. Check result of `$(parsed).find("br:first")[0]` in console.

Comment: thank you your comments. I used same on console and i got an output <br>

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myString = "<b>key1 :  ABCD <br>Date : 2016-10-18-18-38-29<br>Output: /acddfd/example</b>";

//Break string from date
var myDate = myString.substr(myString.indexOf("Date : ")+"Date : ".length);

//Remove string after date
myDate = myDate.substr(0,myDate.indexOf("<br>"));
console.log(myDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
var input="<html>↵<head>↵<h1>↵Example : ↵<br>Explanation↵</h1>↵<hr>↵<b>key1 :  ABCD <br>key2 : 2016-10-18-18-38-29<br>Output: /acddfd/example</b>↵</html>↵";

var b_text = $(input).find( 'h1' ).text();
```

Comment: Question is about get `2016-10-18-18-38-29` part of text not all of text.